# cosh() without math.c library in C language

Tags: c, math, hyperbolic-function

I need to calculate the cosh(x), but I can not use the math.c library, any idea how can I solve it?
This is in C language.

Comment: This sounds more like a math problem then a programming problem.

Comment: Why can't you use the standard library?  If you are working on some embedded system that just doesn't have a math library, then try to find some existing implementation which is good, and port it.  If you're trying to write one from scratch as an exercise or as homework, then you should explain your thoughts / progress / code so far.

Comment: I presume you know how to write `cosh` in terms of `exp`, but that you're not allowed to use `exp` either?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) to [represent cosh](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950655/does-this-series-that-resembles-the-maclaurin-series-of-cosh-x-converge).

cosh(x) = 1 + x ^ 2 / 2! + x ^ 4 / 4! + x ^ 6 / 6! + x ^ 8 / 8! + ....

```
double cosh(double x)
{
    double c, f, xp;
    c = f = xp = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) // You can increase the number of terms to get better precision
    {
        f *= (2 * i - 1) * (2 * i);
        xp *= x * x;
        c += xp / f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I beleive `exp()` needs the math library too.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are correct.

Comment: Upvote following the edit.